# Sending binary data though POST

Tags: asp.net

I'm using `system.text.utf8encoding.utf8.getstring` to `convert` a `byte array` to a `string` and then am sending it to my `asp.net` program through a regular web request as a `POST` value. Every now and then, I get an exception

> "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client "

Is it possible to get rid of that?

**EDIT**: never mind, I started `using webclient.uploaddata` to `send` and `receiving` by `request.binaryread` instead, this method doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: if you are using MVC , then use [AllowHtml] attribute for the Model property. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh882339%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) might help you

Answer (score 0):

try to Add below code put to your web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: this is very bad idea, which increases security risks .

Comment: @JSantosh Give me onther solution for it.

Comment: @KaushilMaheta . check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh882339%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Instead of removing  request validation for entire application, we can remove it page level in web forms. and action level in MVC

Comment: Can use for a single page like `<@ Page validateRequest="false" %>`